# Execution interrupted or reached maximum run time in edaplayground

Tags: verilog, edaplayground

Execution interrupted or reached maximum runtime.

Here is the link for my code:
http://www.edaplayground.com/x/CX8

I am trying to swap numbers in this design.

Comment: Take a look at [How to Ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is not a problem of EDAPlayground. The code might be buggy somewhere.

Your `always @(*)` block is the main reason your simulation is stuck at a single time stamp. The `*` denotes that if **any** RHS variable changes its value, then execute whole block. Here, the variables a_reg and b_reg are continuously swapped on a **single time slot**. Instead, use `always @(posedge clk)`.

To get a more clear idea refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919634/using-always-meaning-and-drawbacks) link.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do is swap two 4-digit numbers 'a' and 'b'. To do this in verilog, you need to remember that when you use the `always @(posedge clk)` construct, you are actually assigning the old value of the net on the RHS to the register on the LHS.
Thus

`always @(posedge clk)
 begin
   a_out = b;
   b_out = a;
end`

results in the correct operation, without the need for any additional registers. I have created a copy of your edaplayground project and added a few additional test vectors. http://www.edaplayground.com/x/8hk

Comment: @RajeshReddy It would help if you mark an answer as the correct solution, if it has helped you